# Switch Rails database connection on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a dev database in my Rails 5 app, but in our network, we also keep a populated database to test stuff on. Sometimes, I have to switch between these databases all the time, and I would save a lot of time if I could do that immediately while Rails is running.

I've tried removing all active connections, and then patching the configuration, but somehow it keeps connecting to my original database.

This is what I tried:

```
Product.count
  => 0 # is dev db

ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.remove_connection('development')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.remove_connection('primary')
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['development'] = test_config_params

Product.count

=> 0 # Is still dev db
```

Where does Rails cache this old connection information, and how can I remove / replace it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change database connections by using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)`. In case `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` is set (Rails automatically loads the contents of config/database.yml into it), a symbol can be given as argument, representing a key in the configuration hash like `:development` or `:test`

Check the complete docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection)